# Can I use Facebook API to post on groups?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-group

Using Facebook SDK, I'm trying to make an Android app and give it the ability to post in Facebook groups. Is that possible?

Comment: Facebook Graph API can be used to post on groups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/group/feed#publish) to achieve that. They said `/{group-id}/feed` used to
*Posts owned by a Group, including status updates and links*. **POST** request to Publish, **GET** to read. Be careful about Permissions.